# Netlogo - problems with the network

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

I'm having trouble finding a way to come across this problem...I have turtles creating a social-network (I use undirected links).

Agents have many variables, among which "y" and "ro". What I would like to know is the mean [ro] of the turtles connected with turtles with [y < 1]...is there a way?

In practice...in the following formula

`mean [ro] of turtles with [link-neighbor? turtle n]`

I would like instead of `turtle n` an agent-set `turtles with [y < 1]`...is there a way?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
turtles-own [y ro]

to test
  ca
  crt 50 [
    set y random-float 2
    set ro one-of [1 2]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    create-links-with n-of 5 other turtles
  ]
  show mean [ro] of (turtles with [has-poor-neighbor])
end

to-report has-poor-neighbor ;turtle proc
  report any? link-neighbors with [y < 1]
end
```